# ko observable object or function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to understand what is the difference between keeping the observable a function or setting it as an object

My observable item:

```
self.SelectedItem = ko.observable();
```

My view:

```
  <div class="collapse" data-bind="with: SelectedItem">
    @Html.Action("Profile", "Team")
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" data-bind="with: ItemForEditing">
    @Html.Action("EditProfile", "Team")
  </div>
```

selecting the item from grid :

```
ko.utils.extend(TeamManager.prototype, {
  selectItem: function (item) {   
    if (typeof item == "undefined") return;  
    this.SelectedItem(item);  
    //this.SelectedItem = item;  
    ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(item), this.ItemForEditing);   
  },

  acceptItem: function (itemData) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(itemData, {}, this.SelectedItem);
  },
```

Why is my binding on the view only working if observable `SelectedItem` is called as a function, eg `this.SelectedItem(item);`, and not as an assignment, eg `this.SelectedItem = item;`.  The latter causes the partial view to not render.

If I use it like this `this.SelectedItem(item);` it's all ok - why do I need to use it this way?

Comment: And could you tell us what is stored in `item`?

Comment: `item` it is been taken from grid  
`data-bind="click: $selectItem"` it's an object with all properties observable    
self.TeamsModel($.map(data, function (item) { return ko.mapping.fromJS(item); }));

Comment: All I can say is that it's hard to know why it's not rendering. Usually when something is wrong with knockout, you should see an error in the console. Anything? if you do `console.log(item)`  what does it show?. May be the format of the object isn't correct. Most likely that somewhere you're using `this.SelectedItem` as an observable. If you set an object, somewhere, it will try to call `SelectedItem` and crash because objects aren't callable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In knockout.js, all observables are formed as a function containing a data. As there was no really easy wait to track changes on object with `=`, the dev of knockoutjs decided that instead of using getter/setter methods on objects, the use of function would be the easiest way to achieve tracking changes.

Getter/Setter on objects are new features that aren't available on older browsers, but calling a JavaScript function is available and you have access to the method that called this method aka `arguments.callee`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/arguments/callee

In order to be able to achieve tracking, whenever you call the observable method, it will build a dependency tree using the callee and this way, KnockoutJS is able to know what to update whenever en observable is being called.

Let say you have this object:

`t.fun = ko.Observable(10)`

Whenever, you use the method. `t.fun()` you're actually calling the method but knockout would register this place as a place that requires to be called letter when the value of `fun` will change.

When you call `t.fun(value)` it will trigger a change and will call again those places that were already called.

This lead to why on knockout, every observable have to be called at least once, to catch any change. If you don't call in any way, `t.fun()` anywhere, knockoutjs doesn't have any idea that this part of your code depends on `t.fun`.

Also, whenever you affect `t.fun` to anything else..

`t.foo = t.fun`.

`t.foo` should work exactly like `t.fun`.

For that reason, if you set a value in your object. It's always a value an unlike some other languages, `t.fun = 1` isn't updating `t.fun` but replacing the value of `t.fun` by `1`. It's possible that JavaScript could do update on basic types, but in the case of Objects, you're affecting a plain new value and there is nothing JavaScript can do to know if the value changed.

AngularJS on the other hand, is checking for a value change by comparing an old value to a new value. KnockoutJS instead is just tracking value changes so no comparison is required in any way.

here's an example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gatnfbao/1/

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. 
        // It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName,
        // because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes
```

You can see that the computed field is using `this.firstName` and `this.lastName()`, it will tell knockout that the `computed` field is basing it self on `lastName`. What happens is that when knockoutjs boots, it will try to call every `ko.computed` variables to add them to the dependency tree. You can see that in our viewModel, the field fullname is correctly computed: `Planet Earth!`. Yet if you modify the field in the input text, it will not change anything in the `ko.computed`. But if you change the "Last Name" field, it will update the `fullName` taking into account of both fields because they are both present. And if you modify `firstName` you'll see the result only and only when `lastName` is changed.

But now, we'll change a bit the code to make you understand that when you modify `lastName` you see that the computed value use the correct value of `firstName` as a side effect of `lastName` being an observable but `firstName` wasn't... Lets remove all observables! https://jsfiddle.net/gatnfbao/2/

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes
```

Notice that now the computed field is using `this.lastName` not `this.lastName()`. Now knockout doesn't have any idea to what this `computed` value is depending on.

The `ko.computed` will be called once with the values `Planet` and `Earth`, but as it isn't using an observable, `ko.computed` has no idea what's going on in there. For that reason, if you modify the field `firstName` or `lastName`, then `fullName` is never updated. It was computed with the initial value but it wasn't containing any observable.

Comment: I understand , but my problem is why in some cases the object with observable properties is working , and in other cases I **have** to use an observable function with all properties observable. thank you for your answer

Comment: all of your observable properties are observable functions. If they aren't observable functions, then your properties are not observables by knockout. Which means, that a change to `normal` properties will not trigger any change if they are modified. If at the same time an observable is changed, then you'll see the change when the observing function will be called. But without observable functions, no change will be ever triggered.

Comment: I understand , but my question is about the item itself **the parent**
I have edited the question , as you can see I am using SelectedItem & ItemForEditing, the editing item is used as object and it's working

I am looking for an example 
http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

but a little more complex , with computed items
and one more thing , I am not using a viewmodel in js 
    $.map(data, function (item) { return ko.mapping.fromJS(item); }));

Comment: @Zyku you're always using a view model in knockout. It doesn't have to be a specific object. A view model is simply an object. It's just a naming for anything that you use in knockout to render a view. It's a model for a view. So, in your case `selectedItem` is an attribute of your view model.

Comment: yes, I understand `SelectedItem` & `ItemForEditing` are properties of my model, but one is a function and the other one is a object , both bind to each div, but `SelectedItem` works only if it's a function, if it's an object the partial view it is not rendered. It's very probable that I am doing something wrong, and I thank you for your anwers

Answer (score 3):

That's just [how observables work](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables).  A knockout observable turns your property/variable into a function.  To get the value from it, you have to call the function with no parameters.  To set the value, you call it with the new value.  The act of calling the function with the new value allows knockout to update any subscriptions, including your bindings.

When you do:

```
this.SelectedItem = item;
```

`SelectedItem` is no longer an `observable`, it's been updated to point directly at the `item`, so no bindings will update.

---

Having said that, if you're working in a modern environment, one of the main authors of knockout has made [a plugin](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/) that allows more usual property access, where an assignment would work.

Comment: I know , but all properties from the object are observables

Comment: @Zyku But as soon as you do `someobservable = somevalue`, it's no longer an observable, it's just the value of `somevalue`.  You have to update it through the function call (unless you use a plugin as mentioned in my answer).